# python forward SIGINT to subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, signals, signal-handling

Here is a simple Python script that spawn a process:

```
import subprocess
import os

subprocess.run(['ping', '-i', '30', 'google.fr'],
               preexec_fn=lambda : os.setpgrp())
```

When I `kill -TERM <python-pid>`, it stops the `python` process, but the `ping` process continue running: that's what I was expecting.

But when I `kill -INT <python-pid>`, both `python` and `ping` processes are stopped. This is different from `CTRL-V` which send the `SIGINT` to the process group, not just the process. Anyway, the `setpgrp` make the `ping` process become the leader of its own process group.

So I suppose that somewhere in Python code, `SIGINT` is sent ot the `ping` child, but `SIGTERM` is not, but where is this code, and where is it documented?

**Edit**: I'm running Python 3.6 on Debian 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is in [`subprocess.run`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/subprocess.py#L447), the function you called. `SIGINT` gets converted into a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception, which is handled by an `except` clause that calls `process.kill()`. You could implement different handling of `SIGINT` using the [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) module. Notably, `kill` doesn't send `SIGINT` but sends `SIGKILL`, so the subprocess does not get a chance to do similar handling with this default cleanup.

Comment: Indeed, using directly `Popen`, `kill -INT <python-pid>` do not stop the `ping` process.

Comment: @DavidFroger Is there a way to get this behavior? Of guaranteed killing the child when a SIGKILL is passed?